# JavaScript & JQuery Labeling Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code gives me an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label" error when logged to the console.

I've done quite a bit research and I have a theory for the cause, but I can't find any documentation that will help me find a solution. In most cases, the error happens when someone does not put the JS label directly before the loop. In some cases, someone's label is getting invisibly glitched by things like JSCover putting in unexpected brackets.

Anyway, I think this is an issue with my JQuery $.getJSON function; but I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone assist me by explaining to me why the getJSON is creating the label issue, and identity if there are any other problems? I'm only using a label because my loop wasn't stopping with a while loop; even if it was hitting my else statement. If you have a suggestion to alter the code, it would be much appreciated.

```
featuredLoop:
for(priorityActive = 0; priorityActive < streamerLength; priorityActive++){
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer[i];
        $.getJSON(url,function(data1){
            if(data1.stream === null){
                i++;
                continue featuredLoop;
            }else if(data1.stream != null){
                activeStreamer = streamer[i];
                streamerDetails();
                break featuredLoop;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The function called inside getJSON is an asynchronous method. thats your issue.

Comment: I would not recommend to use labels. I have never seen their need. Never loop ajax. Instead call again in succes or done. This is an X/Y problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it i believe.

```js
var i = 0,
  streamer = [] //some array;

function getStreamer(i) {
  if (i < streamerLength) {
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer[i];
    $.getJSON(url, function(data1) {
      if (data1.stream === null) {
        i++;
        getStreamer(i);
      } else if (data1.stream != null) {
        activeStreamer = streamer[i];
        streamerDetails();
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("not found");
  }
}
```

Comment: That did not work. I appreciate the response, thank you.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error, but my content isn't loading. It should be looping until it displays content on my page via the "streamerDetails(); function. It's not displaying anything. After testing, it doesn't look like it's ever hitting the inside of the else if; and I verified that it should. (The data1.stream should not be null for the third person in the array)

Comment: and is the loop going till 3rd person? what happens if you put a `console.log(i)` in the `if(data1.stream===null)` block? does it reach to 2? if not, `streamerLength` will be less than 2. idk where this variable comes from. you'd know better.

Comment: I'm an idiot. You are a genius. Thank you, senpai. I'm running on no sleep right now, I never put in the getStreamer(i); to run the function. It seems to be working exactly how I wanted, but it is popping up a lot of errors in the console now. (Example: global-144ed71….js:29 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED) is the first error.

Comment: @user118939 arigato user-chan! Also, could you post the complete error log? it's really hard to tell what's going on from what you gave in example.